# Allow HTML to be submitted from textarea input?

Tags: html, textarea

How do I allow HTML to be submitted from textarea, I am really desparate on this, every answer I found gives me poor info, coz I don't have idea what to do.

I have this textarea:

```
<input id="mytextarea" name="mytextarea" type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php _e('iframe'); ?>">
```

or:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea" name="mytextarea" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('iframe'); ?>"></textarea>
```

I want HTML to stay as it is after submission, in my case html is removed.

Comment: The `<textarea>` tag doesn't have a `value` property.  The value goes in between the opening and closing tag: `<textarea>Stuff</textarea>`

Comment: What do you mean by "submitted"? Submitted to a server?

Comment: why dont you use AJAX?

Comment: Hi, Mike Christensen. I don't have any error, but HTML is stripped after it's submitted. If I submit youtube old or new iframe embed it will dissapear. I am doing this in wordpress, but I found that I can add html throught backend, but can't throught textarea, so I have to enable it somehow to be submited from this textarea. I read something about how to enable htmlspecialchars in one post, but still have no idea how to... My bad for value, I thought codes are same for input and textarea.

Comment: @PoloPakina - Probably depends on your web server.  I know IIS blocks those sorts of requests unless you disable some sort of checking.  Maybe something similar is going on for you.

Comment: mad_programmer, I have this textarea in one plugin, any bigger change will broke the plugin functions, I can play around just this textarea to enable html submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML  tag only accepts plain (unformatted) text. Even if you add HTML to it, or try to format it, it will be removed. What you need to do is use a Rich Text Editor. There are many you can use, for example [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).
You can use these editors in HTML mode (source code mode) and do what you’re trying to do.

Comment: That means I have to add editor to custom fields in wordpress. To much new experience for iframe, I will go with shortcodes. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but how does TinyMCE do it? For example, you can copy-paste HTML tables from word documents or websites directly into TinyMCE. What browser capabilities are they using to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Textarea accepts any text to be stored in TEXT, VARCHAR etc. field in database.
To see HTML formatted text use "html_entity_decode" in php.

For example to HTML format WP descripton:

In database - in wp_options table change 'option_value' field from VARCHAR to TEXT

In header change:

```
<h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
```

to

```
<h2 class="site-description"><?php echo html_entity_decode(get_bloginfo('description')); ?></h2>
```

In admin you can change

```
<td><textarea name="blogdescription" type="textarea" id="blogdescription" class="regular-text"  cols="67" rows="7" /><?php form_option('blogdescription'); ?>"</textarea>
```

Now the 'textarea' stores all text you entered including HTML tags and you can see formatted text on your Blog header

Hope I got your point and it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ejs you can format your tag like: <%- ... %> rather than 
<%= ... %>.