# How to allow people to enter HTML into a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am using a web page and i would like to know how i can allow people to enter HTML Markup into my textbox below?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTsCs"
             runat="server"
             tabindex="7"
             placeholder="Terms & Conditions"
             TextMode="MultiLine"
             Width="210px"
             Height="254px">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Someone answered this question a couple years ago but the same general rules will apply. [Here's][1] a link to the question.  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756573/allow-html-to-be-submitted-from-textarea-input

Comment: Do you want to handle this at the server or is javascript ok?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have to add the ValidateRequest="false" tag. But that would disable the Request Validation and let your whole page accept unencoded HTML, which can be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

You can use javascript encoding / HTML encoding to work-around the issue.

I used to check links like the one below, I hope it helps you.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1581971.aspx?Allow+HTML+tags+in+TextBox+control

Comment: Hey man thanks for the help, but we arent too worried about attacks. This site will only be for a couple users to create campaign Vouchers for MSC Cruises. So It shouldnt be too much of a problem since its going to be used by their company only and not customers. But thanks anyways @Denchu

Comment: Sure thing :) Just added it for further reference if needed :)

Answer (score 2):

In your .aspx page add ValidateRequest="false" just like below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestWeb.WebForm1" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```